# Image not acting as expected when trying to get it to appear using a hover effect. Perhaps because of javascript scroll animation

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am building a personal website. Currently working on the project section of the website. Each project has a card that is stacked using grid. I want two things to happen when you hover over a card. The first is a project caption that replaces the project title in the card. The second is a project image appearing to the right of all the cards that acts as a project thumbnail. I have added the scroll animation, and caption functionality.

But my image no matter what I try, seems to either be always invisible (regardless of toggling the opacity) or doesn't seem to adhere to the JS function.

I am trying to teach myself webdevelopment through exploration and I feel like my code base is sloppy to say the least. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried moving the image div around in my HTML. I have tried editing my JS function. I have tried chat GPT.
Here is my HTML for the project section (I have 3 sections):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".card-automaton").hover(
    function() {

      $(this).find(".Automaton").css("opacity", "0");
      console.log("this code is running");
      $(this).find(".automaton-caption").css("opacity", "1");
      $(this).find(".automaton-picture").css("opacity", "1");

    },
    function() {
      $(this).find(".Automaton").css("opacity", "1");
      $(this).find(".automaton-caption").css("opacity", "0");
      $(this).find(".automaton-picture").css("opacity", "0");
    }
  );
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#header {
  background-color: #393E46;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.main-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.logo-picture {
  width: 3.5%;
  border: 1px solid #00ADB5;
}

.logo-picture:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.connect,
.hugo-barnes,
.projects {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.connect {
  background-color: #222831;
}

.hugo-barnes {
  background-color: #222831;
}

.projects {
  background-color: #222831;
}

.scroll-up {
  transform: translateY(20%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 2s, opacity 2s;
}

.scroll-up.appear {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.profile-picture {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 33%;
  right: 85px;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 1px solid #00ADB5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

.hugo-barnes-title {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.about-text {
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #00ADB5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.project-title {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 325px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.project-cards {
  position: inherit;
  margin-top: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 250px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 250px);
  gap: 8px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
  border: 1px solid #00ADB5;
}

.card-the-kings-quest {
  background-color: #393E46;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
  border: solid #00ADB5;
  font-size: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-automaton,
.card-matrix-master,
.card-word-wizard,
.card-grid-genius {
  background-color: #393E46;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: span 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  grid-row: span 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid #00ADB5;
}

.automaton-caption,
.matrix-master-caption {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tkq-caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.word-wizard-caption {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid-genius-caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.project-thumbnails {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1020px;
  top: 995px;
}

.automaton-picture {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 52%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="projects" id="projectsid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="project-title scroll-up">Projects</h1>
    <div class="project-cards">
      <div class="card card-automaton scroll-up">
        <p class="Automaton">Automaton</p>
        <div class="automaton-caption">
          <p>
            Arduino
            <br> Powered
            <br> Drawing
            <br> Machine
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-thumbnails">
          <img src="../images/Project-Thumbnails/Drawing Machine Thumbnail.png" class="automaton-picture ">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-matrix-master scroll-up">
        <p class="Matrix-Master">Matrix Master</p>
        <div class="matrix-master-caption">
          <p>
            Python
            <br>Powered
            <br>Sudoku
            <br>Solver
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-the-kings-quest scroll-up">
        <p class="TKQ">T <br> K <br> Q</p>
        <div class="tkq-caption">
          <p>
            The
            <br> King's
            <br> Quest
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-word-wizard scroll-up">
        <p class="Word-Wizard">Word Wizard</p>
        <div class="word-wizard-caption">
          <p>
            Python
            <br>Powered
            <br>Pangram
            <br>Finder
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-grid-genius scroll-up">
        <p class="Grid-Genius">Grid Genius</p>
        <div class="grid-genius-caption">
          <p>
            Machine
            <br>Learning
            <br>Crossword
            <br>Solver
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I would suggest to go easier if you are still learning the basics. Make sure you have your mind clear with the html/css before addressing the javascript part. Here for example you have the css rule for `.scroll-up` that hides everything to begin with.. and the class `appear` that would show things.. but none of those are taken into account by the js code

Comment: I edited the question copying your exact code inside a live snippet.. as you can see the problem is bigger than what you described.. everything is hidden and the hover part is a detail that comes later.. what are you supposed to be hovering if you can't see anything

Comment: anyway just to give you a glimpse of something usable, just comment `opacity: 0;` in the css rule aimed at the `.scroll-up` selector

Comment: one last thing.. I didn't tell yet that technically the reason why nothing is showing up is because the `scroll-up` class (holding the `opacity:0`) is set for the parent element of `.Automaton` (and for each card indeed) so even if you change the opacity of its child, the parent wins and hides everything anyway.